# Why the canvas doesn't appear in the window when i play the app i made?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, canvas

Why the canvas does not appear in the app I'm trying to make, (the paint app), even though I made the code exactly as the video tutorial which is this code the one for the canvas, Is there something badly written in it?

```py
canvas = Canvas(window)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
canvas.bind('<Button -1>', locate_xy)
canvas.bind('<B1 -Motion>', addLine)
```

It doesn't say that isn't working, it just doesn't appear the canvas in the window, I don't know why. I would appreciate any help

Comment: Try adding `width` and `height` options in `Canvas(...)`. Also if the background color of the canvas is the same as the window, you cannot see it.

Comment: as @acw1668 suggested with background color - first you could use `Canvas( ..., bg="red")` to change background and see where is your canvas in window. You may do the same with other widgets to see if then don't use full space and then there is no space for Canvas. Other problem can be size - in some situations it may not resize Canvas and it may size `0x0` - so you could test with `Canvas( ..., width=800, height=600)`

Comment: if you build it with some tutorial then you could add link to tutorial. I would be also simpler if you would add all code because problem can makes other widgets (ie. use all space, lay on top of canvas and hide it, etc.)

Comment: Ok here's the link to the tutorial which I made exactly as the video; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfUC4l09TX0&t=354s